# Browserify 'browser' option ignored when requiring from node_module

Tags: javascript, browserify

Say I have the following (typical) project structure:

```
index.js
package.json
mymodule2.js
node_modules
|-- nice_module
|   |-- module1.js
|   |-- module2.js
|   |== package.json
```

The nice_module contains two files: module1.js and module2.js while module1 requires module2.

my index.js requires node_modules/module/module1.js, however I would like to override module2 with mymodule2.js that I've wrote - for this matter I have added the following entry into my package.json file:

```
browser: {
    "module2" : "./mymodule2.js"
}
```

well - this doesn't work - it still requires nice_module/module2, however if I remove package.json from nice_module it works as I expected.

I understand why it is happening - Browserify recursively bundle each module using its own package.json file. in that case - how can I override modules globally? is there any relevant configuration?

The way I see to deal with it at the moment is to write gulp or grunt task that copies module1.js into different folder and require it from my index.js file, however it feels to me a bit clumsy solution..

Thanks!

Comment: Why do you need to override the module? If it's for testing purposes, have you considered [proxyquireify](https://github.com/thlorenz/proxyquireify)?

Comment: Not exactly for testing but quite close - I would like my module to require different module in development environment.
It seems that proxyquireify can also be in my favor here - thanks!

Comment: If you are able to solve your problem with it, make sure you come back and answer your own question.